# Поиск в коллекции по нескольким полям

Tags: c#, .net

Необходимо сделать эффективный поиск в коллекции кастомных объектов по нескольким полям. Коллекция содержит около 1 млн. объектов.

Поиск по одному полю (число, строка) делается через словарь:

```
var dict = new Dictionary<string, MyClass>();
dict.Add("key1", new MyClass() { StrId = "key1" });
var obj = dict["key1"];
```

А вот как сделать поиск по нескольким полям? Например, по двум строковым и одному числовому.

Спасибо.

Comment: (1) Ваш набор полей для поиска всегда один и тот же? Если да, почему бы не положить его ключом в `Dictionary`. (2) А не нужна ли вам база данных? :-)

Comment: @VladD 1. Да, набор полей один. Точнее их несколько под разные задачи. Это типа эмуляции индексов получается. 2. Данные загружены в память для ускорения работы. Запросы должны обрабатываться до 100 мс, а таблиц более 40.

Comment: Тогда `Dictionary<Tuple<T1, T2, T3>, MyClass>` и есть аналог индекса :)

Comment: Может быть, вам нужна in-memory database? Попробуйте, может оказаться и нормально по производительности.

Comment: @VladD А какие in-memory рекомендуете посмотреть?

Comment: @VladD Наверное, будут накладные расходны на IPC к отдельному процессу базы. Сериализация всякая лишняя появится... Это все снизит скорость вычислений.

Comment: Перенес в отдельный вопрос про in-memory: http://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/459555/%D0%92%D1%8B%D0%B1%D0%BE%D1%80-in-memory-%D0%B1%D0%B0%D0%B7%D1%8B-%D0%B4%D0%B0%D0%BD%D0%BD%D1%8B%D1%85

Comment: В Вы тестировали скорость работы реляционных БД? Что у вас получалось по времени?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Определите кастмный тип ключа - структуру или класс с тремя полями. В случае класса - определите `Equals` и `GetHashCode` для сравнения по всем полям.

Или используйте Tuple - это готовая структура - кортеж:

```
var dict = new Dictionary<Tuple<string, int>, MyClass>();
dict.Add(Tuple.Create("key1", 42), new MyClass() { StrId = "key1" });

var obj = dict[Tuple.Create("key1", 42)];
```

Answer (score 1):

Если вам требуется искать по любому из нескольких полей - надо просто сделать несколько словарей. По словарю на каждое поле:

```
public class TwoIndexCollection {

  private readonly Dictionary<string, MyClass> index1 = new Dictionary<string, MyClass>();
  private readonly Dictionary<int, MyClass> index2 = new Dictionary<int, MyClass>();

  public void Add (MyClass m) {
    index1.Add(m.field1, m);
    try { index2.Add(m.field2, m); }
    catch { index1.Remove(m.field1); throw; }
  }

  public MyClass GetByField1(string value) {
    return index1[value];
  }

  public MyClass GetByField2(int value) {
    return index2[value];
  }
}
```

Если одновременно - то можно воспользоваться кортежами:

```
public class CompositeIndexCollection {

  private readonly Dictionary<Tuple<string, int>, MyClass> index = 
    new Dictionary<Tuple<string, int>, MyClass>();

  public void Add (MyClass m) {
    index.Add(Tuple.Create(m.field1, m.field2), m);
  }

  public MyClass Get(string key1, int key2) {
    return index[Tuple.Create(key1, key2)];
  }
}
```

или же можно воспользоваться анонимными объектами:

```
public class CompositeIndexCollection {

  private readonly Dictionary<object, MyClass> index = new Dictionary<object, MyClass>();

  public void Add (MyClass m) {
    index.Add(new { m.field1, m.field2 }, m);
  }

  public MyClass Get(string key1, int key2) {
    return index[new { field1 = key1, field2 = key2 }];
  }
}
```

Возможна ситуация, когда с одним и тем же ключом допустимо существование нескольких объектов. Тогда придется хранить в словаре не 1 значение, а их список.

---

PS но миллион записей - это в любом случае довольно много. Рассмотрите вариант хранения их в БД.

Comment: 1. Да, нужно именно одновременно. 2. Интересно, какая будет функция вычисления хеша у анонимных объектов? Оно вообще будет работать? С кортежами понятно: (((h1 << 5) + h1) ^ h2) 3.База данных не подходит. См. мой комент к вопросу.

Comment: @bobinshtein, скачайте ILSpy и посмотрите. Да, работать анонимные объекты будут.

Answer (score 0):

А почему вы не хотите использовать LINQ ?

```
dict.FirstOrDefault(x => x.Key == "key1" && x.Value.StrId  == "key1")
```

Подробнее [тут](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/vstudio/bb549039%28v=vs.90%29.aspx)

Comment: *"Коллекция содержит около 1 млн. объектов."* Только линейного поиска по миллиону элементов автору вопроса и не хватало... Хватит уже вредительские ответы публиковать!

Comment: @PavelMayorov , аргументируйте пожалуйста. Хватит уже пустословить

Comment: @V319 сложность поиска по хешу O(1), ваш вариант даёт O(n).

Comment: @V319, вообще-то я аргументировал. Не моя вина, что фраза "линейный поиск по миллиону элементов" ничего вам не говорит.

Comment: @PavelMayorov , говорит-говорит, однако я не уверен, что в вышеупомянутых масштабах это заметно скажется на быстродействии

Comment: @V319: Выкатите бенчмарк?

Comment: @V319 ваш вариант по на моей машине отрабатывает за 35ms (на словаре в 1М элементов). у топикастера общий лимит - порядка 100ms. т.е. он может сделать два с половиной поиска - маловато будет.