# Выбор in-memory базы данных

Tags: база-данных, хранилище

Необходимо сделать эффективный поиск в коллекции кастомных объектов по нескольким полям. Коллекция содержит около 1 млн. объектов.

Сейчас сделено через словари/хеш-таблицы в приложении.

Коллеги, [предлагают](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/459541/%D0%9F%D0%BE%D0%B8%D1%81%D0%BA-%D0%B2-%D0%BA%D0%BE%D0%BB%D0%BB%D0%B5%D0%BA%D1%86%D0%B8%D0%B8-%D0%BF%D0%BE-%D0%BD%D0%B5%D1%81%D0%BA%D0%BE%D0%BB%D1%8C%D0%BA%D0%B8%D0%BC-%D0%BF%D0%BE%D0%BB%D1%8F%D0%BC) посмотреть в сторону in-memory базы данных.
Какие порекомендуете?

Смущают дополнительные накладные расходны на IPC из приложения в БД.

Comment: Тут скорее не in-memory, а NoSQL. Если вам нужен именно быстрый поиск. Я бы посмотрел в сторону MongoDB: https://www.mongodb.org/

Comment: @bobinshtein а на чем собрались писать?

Comment: @Barmaley пишем на .net, но, наверное, это не должно влиять...

Comment: Обычный SQL Server - тоже вполне in-memory - он кэширует все подряд. и можно еще Columnstore Indexes включить - которые явно в памяти лежат. Так что в ответе можно дать любой %yourfavoritedb%. Уточните вопрос - может быть вам не быстрый поиск нужен, а обычный кэш.

Comment: @PashaPash обычная бд работает не очень быстро. нужно отвечать до 100 мс на довольно большое количество вычислений и обращений к данным.

Comment: @bobinshtein SQL Server вполне способен отвечать в пределах пары миллисекунд. На самом деле он работает очень быстро, даже на обычных индексах. Я к тому, что у вас вопрос слишком общий. Можно насоветовать все что угодно, от Dictionary до SQL Server или Redis, или Mongodb.

Answer (score 0):

Hypersonic SQL DB , он же [HSQLDB](http://hsqldb.org/) вне конкуренции.

Года 3-4 назад писал аппу, где как раз нужен был in-memory DB. После различных мучений остановился на HSQLDB.

Есть еще [Derby](https://db.apache.org/derby/), который входит в состав Java, но мне показался тяжеловатым.

В последнее время стал модным [SQLite](https://www.sqlite.org/) в телефонах Android/iOS он понужается вовсю.

Comment: SQLite - не in-memory

Comment: @PavelMayorov SQLite in-memory https://www.sqlite.org/inmemorydb.html

Comment: ладно, уговорили

Comment: Тут, наварное, еще нужно различать in-memory где. SqlLite запускается в процессе приложения, а другие же работают как отдельные процессы, но все держат в памяти.